# SQL - Nested Select Statements with Max?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have one table and in this table is PostDate and OrderNo and a bunch of other fields. I would like to get all the latest PostDates and then with those PostDates get the largest OrderNo. I would then like to show one row that shows the PostDate and that OrderNo.

So far I below. This shows me all the rows with postdates from yesterday and now I want to show only the largest OrderNo in those PostDates. I tried using a nested select but I could not wrap my head around it. Any clever ideas?

```
SELECT OrderNo, PostDate
FROM    table
WHERE   PostDate = (SELECT MAX(PostDate) FROM table
```

Comment: Sorry, it is MSSQL 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the order number, you can use MAX again since you know the post date will also be the MAX due to your subselect:

```
SELECT MAX(OrderNo), MAX(PostDate)
FROM    table
WHERE   PostDate = (SELECT MAX(PostDate) FROM table)
```

Comment: Also, if OrderNo is incremental, you don't need the subselect at all as the largest number is also going to be on the max date. Is this the case?

Comment: I believe it is incremental based on date, would that make a difference?

Comment: As in it starts over at 1 each day?

Comment: I am not sure as I did not design the system , I believe it starts at some number each year or at the financial cycle for this company.

Comment: ah ok then, well if you can't trust the OrderNo to be conventionally incremental then the query as above with the max sub select is probably the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to drop the `WHERE` with the `MAX` altogether, order the rows in such a way that the row that you want is at the top, and limit the output to a single row.

The last step (limiting the output to one row) is dependent on SQL version. Here is how to do it in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    OrderNo, PostDate
FROM My_Table
ORDER BY PostDate DESC, OrderNo Desc
```

Comment: I get this error, Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @David This is very strange. Do you use this query by itself, or within some larger statement? Did you copy it exactly as is, including with the `TOP 1` part?

Comment: @David Here is a [link to a working example on MS SQL 2014](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/228d1/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a RDBMS which supports ranking

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo DESC) AS Rnk
           OrderNo, PostDate
    FROM    table
    WHERE   PostDate = (SELECT MAX(PostDate) FROM table)
)
SELECT * FROM C
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For `MS-SQL` use `TOP 1` with `Order by` something like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrderNo, PostDate
FROM    table
WHERE   PostDate = (SELECT MAX(PostDate) FROM table
order by OrderNo desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
SELECT PostDate, Max(OrderNo)
FROM table
GROUP BY PostDate;
```

do what you want? From your description, I think it would.  This will list the maximum order per date.  Alternatively, depending on how I interpret the spec (I'm trying to wrap my head around the wording), this might do it:

```
SELECT 
    Max(OrderNo) as MaxOrderNoForMaxPostDate,
    (SELECT MAX(PostDate) FROM Table) as MaxPostDate
FROM table
WHERE Postdate = (SELECT Max(PostDate) FROM table)
```

Comment: The first one did not work, it shows me a lot of data. I did not try the second one.